# java githubApi getRemaining requests

Tags: api, github, client

I am trying to use githubapi to get the remaining requests but client.getRemainingrequests return -1. I post my code bellow

```
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
    client = userService.getClient().setCredentials("#######@gmail.com", "#####");;

    System.out.println("remaining requests:"+client.getRequestLimit());
```

Comment: +1 for sharing your username and password with the world :)

Comment: Ivan, if you don't have the answer don't waste my time and yours, i have done mistake,  with copy paste i take my credentials but believe me nobody cares about my github credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jcabi-github](http://github.jcabi.com/index.html) instead:

```
Github github = new RtGithub(oauth_token);
int remaining = github.limits().get("core").json().getInt("remaining");
```

Much simpler and object-oriented.